# calling a function twice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function twice, but with the current code I have getPoints() function  is skipped and the getPoints() function in the setInterval is called. I am trying to make it call the getPoints() function and then call the one inside the setInterval.

```
var background;
// background page
background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
// get totals
getPoints(background.localStorage.points);
// update every 30 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("func");
  getPoints(background.localStorage.points);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console for errors? My guess is that the getPoints function is defined after that code is run. This would cause the first call to fail, but the setInterval call to succeed, because the function is defined by the time the interval is hit.

Comment: You can give some `console.log` in the function `getPoints()` to find out whether it is getting called or is terminating due to some other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var background;
    // background page
    background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    // get totals
    getPoints(background.localStorage.points);
    // update every 30 seconds
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log("func");
        getPoints(background.localStorage.points);
    }, 30000);
};
```